# probleme with submitting a form in jquery dialog within form jsf

Tags: jquery, javabeans, jsf-2.2

I have a form in jsf in this form I have a couple of buttons. When I click the button a jquery dialog appears . the problem is I have another form in this dialog which contains  input text to be submitted to the database by a command button and I don't know how to do this . Here is the code:

```js
//her is the code of jquery to open a dialog:


$("#AVG").click(function () {
     $("#dialog1").dialog(
     {
         title: "AVG",
         autoOpen: false,
      show:"explode",
      hide:"explode",
         position :{  my: "right bottom", at: "left top",of: "#AVG"}         
      });
     
     $("#dialog1").dialog("open").show();
     return false;
});
```

```html
<h:form id="myform" prependId="false">
<button id="AVG" type="button">Montage_AVG</button>      
<div  id="dialog1" title="AVG">
<h:form id="myform1">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" >
 <h:outputLabel value="matricule :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.matricule}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="position :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.position}"style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="n_serie :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.n_serie}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="marque :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.marque}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="profil :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.profil}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="dimention :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.dimention}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="kilometrage :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.kilometrage_au_montage}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:outputLabel value="DateMontage :"/>
<h:inputText  value="#{pneuBean.date_montage}" style="width:90px;"/>
<h:commandButton   value="Sauvegarder" action="#{pneuBean.addPneu()}">          </h:commandButton>       
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>      
</div>
<h:commandButton value="Sauvegarder" actionListener="#{vehiculeBean.addVehicule}"/>        
 </h:form>
```

and here is the function to call when a click on the button of submit in jquery dialog:

public void addPneu() {

```
    // Service.add( v );
    Pneu p = new Pneu();
    p.setMatricule( matricule );
    p.setPosition( position );
    p.setN_serie( n_serie );
    p.setDate_montage( date_montage );
    p.setMarque( marque );
    p.setProfil( profil );
    p.setDimention( dimention );
    p.setKilometrage_au_montage( kilometrage_au_montage );

    Servicep.add( p );
    // p.setMatricule( matricule );
    // ajout de 4 pneu qui font reference au vehicule v
    // Servicep.add( p );
    // message = "Mr " + nom_propriètaire + " a été ajouter avec succes";
    // System.out.println( matricule + "" + nom_propriètaire + " " +
    // tel_proprètaire );

    matricule = "";
    position = "";
    n_serie = "";
    marque = "";
    profil = "";
    dimention = "";
    kilometrage_au_montage = 0L;

}
```

any help would be appreciated